# TPL - Using static method vs struct method

Tags: c#

I have about 1500 files on a share for which I need to collect FileVersionInfo string. So I created a Static method in my Gateway like this:

```
private static string GetVersionInfo(string filepath)
{
    FileVersionInfo verInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(filepath);
    return string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", verInfo.ProductMajorPart, verInfo.ProductMinorPart,
                                            verInfo.ProductBuildPart, verInfo.ProductPrivatePart).Trim();
}
```

And then used FileAndVersion struct in a PLINQ call with DegreeOfParallelism as this is I/O related

```
resultList = dllFilesRows.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(20)
                    .Select(r =>
                    {
                        var symbolPath = r.Filename;
                        return new FilenameAndVersion{Filename=symbolPath, Version=GetVersionInfo(symbolPath)};
                    })
                    .ToArray();
```

Later I modified the Struct, FileAndVersion as:

```
 private struct FilenameAndVersion 
{
    private string _version, _filename;
    public string Version { get { return _version; } }
    public string Filename { get { return _filename; } }

    private void SetVersion()
    {
        FileVersionInfo verInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(this.Filename);
        this._version = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", verInfo.ProductMajorPart, verInfo.ProductMinorPart,

                                                                                    verInfo.ProductBuildPart, verInfo.ProductPrivatePart).Trim();
}
public FilenameAndVersion(string filename, string version)
{
    this._filename = filename;
    this._version = string.Empty;
    SetVersion();
}
```

}

And used it:

```
resultList = dllFilesRows.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(20)
                    .Select(r =>
                    {
                        var symbolPath = r.Filename;
                        return new FilenameAndVersion(symbolPath, String.Empty);
                    })
                    .ToArray();
```

The question is, is this going to help me in anyway and is a good pattern to use ? 
Forgot to mention that the files are on a server that has RAID 10 with SAN attached to it.

Sunit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your files are on the same disk, doing it in parallel isn't going to help at all. A disk can only read one thing at a time, so you would probably be better of forgetting about parallelism it, ditch the threading overhead and just let it run sequentially.

All you are going to end up with if you run this in parallel is a disk that just thrashes about all over the place and ends up reading slower overall.

If you files are on different physical drives, (or are over a network like FTP), then consider taking a bit more control of the parallelism and dividing it into a single task for each physical disk.

My advice would be to benchmark it before you make any firm commitment to making something parallel.

Comment: The files are on a FileServer that has SAN attached.

Comment: @Sunit: What I have said might still be true. Your network pipe is limited so you might find that parallel vs sequential doesn't make mush differene, you are still bound by the network speed. The only way to know is to benchmark/profile it. I suspect it's probably heavily dependant on the network/san load at the time, so run your tests during peak and off peak hours. You might find that you are better off just putting this whole lot on just 1 background thread which would be mostly idle while waiting for the network and free up the CPU for the GUI or other work.

Comment: Yes I was already profiling using the VS2010 tools. It seems that in our case, the SAN with 10RAID/1Gb network was handling was giving a better result using TPL vs synch IO. So for now we have decided to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

Using the TPL (or any form of parallelism) when dealing with file I/O is actually more likely to slow down execution than speed it up, unless you have some way to guarantee that the files being accessed in parallel are on different physical disks or on a Solid State Disk.  Magnetic storage tends to be much better at sequential I/O than random-access I/O (which you are essentially forcing here).

But, as always, you need to profile and actually measure the impact of the change.

To clarify: Running expensive file operations in the *background* (preferably using I/O completion ports, which `FileVersionInfo` unfortunately does not offer) is a good thing to do, in order to avoid blocking the UI, or the ASP.NET request, depending on your environment.  That is much different from running them in *parallel*, however; the TPL is primarily intended for parallelization of *CPU-intensive* tasks, where multiple CPU cores can help to complete the operation faster.